# Remove shower faucet face plate

Tags: shower, valve

How do I remove the face plate on my shower faucet?  There is a lip I cannot get over without damaging it.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Looks like there's some threads on the inside of the smaller metal ring. Probably was finger tight when installed; now it's crudded on there.

Comment: I agree, I'd hit it with some CLR to try and dissolve some of that gunk.